# Count the elements in the values while groupingBy an attribute in key

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `Map<Owner,  List<Car>>` as `ownerMap`. My `Car` class has the `getColor()` and `getPrice()` methods. My
`Owner` class has the getCity() method.

I want to count the car's grouping by cities. (For example: Budapest:  4 (cars))

This is my code so far :

```
List<String> cities = ownerMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(m -> m.getKey().getCity())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hint: there's a collector called `groupingBy` in the `Collectors` class. And there's even a couple of example at the top of [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And how can i use effectively?

Comment: *How can I improve my skills in java stream?*  is not a good title, please edit your question and put a title which describe your question

Comment: What if you have two owners in the same city selling selling four models of the same car?. Would the count be 4 or 8?

Comment: It wolud be 4+4=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) and [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)).

For example, something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> cities=ownerMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getCity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue().size())));

cities.forEach((name, count) -> {
        System.out.println(name + ":" + count);
    });
```

From the `Collectors.groupingBy` documentation:

> Returns a Collector implementing a cascaded "group by" operation on input elements of type T, grouping elements according to a classification function, and then performing a reduction operation on the values associated with a given key using the specified downstream Collector.

In your case, the classification function is by city (`entry.getKey().getCity()`) and your reduction operation is a sum of Cars list size by key (`entry.getValue().size()`).

**EDITED** Modified to get a sum of cars (list size) by city

Comment: And what if , when at Budapest  list is empty? Or in list ara more than 1 car?

Comment: Perfekt. Thank you!